# Difference Between Two Times with microseconds in php

Tags: php

I'm calculating a difference of time with milliseconds precision in PHP.

I tried the hours, minutes and seconds. How to calculate the milliseconds?

```
$time1 = strtotime('8:01:13.225');
$time2 = strtotime('8:02:11.088');
$diff = $time2 - $time1;
$diffTime = date('H:i:s',$diff);
```

I expect the output of `$time2-$time1` to be `0:00:57.863`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` will parse a time with microseconds, but it ignores them. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> 5.0.0     Microseconds began to be allowed, but they are ignored.

To do math on times with microseconds, you can use [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) objects:

```
$time1 = date_create_from_format('H:i:s.u', '8:01:13.225');
$time2 = date_create_from_format('H:i:s.u', '8:02:11.088');
$diff = $time2->diff($time1);
echo $diff->format('%H:%I:%s.%f');
```

Output:

```
00:00:57.863000
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/16l53)

**Update**

It seems some versions of PHP7+ do strange things with microseconds, keeping them as a negative value, resulting in an output of

```
00:00:58.-137000
```

To work around that, you can use this code:

```
$time1 = date_create_from_format('H:i:s.u', '8:01:13.225');
$time2 = date_create_from_format('H:i:s.u', '8:02:11.088');
$diff = $time2->diff($time1);
// correct for weird microseconds behaviour
$secs = $diff->s + (float)$diff->format('%f') / 1000000;
echo $diff->format("%H:%I:$secs");
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tFuIb)

Comment: yes its right but i exceute in phpfiddle.Difference in Output

Comment: I am using php version : - 7.3.3

Comment: @rajan what output do you get?

Comment: The version is Problem i got output like 00:00:58.%f; i check my php version and exceute once again it got correct Output .Thanks a lot

Comment: @rajan I've made an update to the code which deals with some strange behaviour in other versions of PHP7.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do with `DateTime` object

```
<?php
$time1 = new DateTime('8:01:13.225');
$time2 = new DateTime('8:02:11.088');
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%s.%f');
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/AjOFD